# Из input вывести в div

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

В input вводишь дату, время, текст - все это через запятую.
Это все нужно вывести в div, но не просто как текст, а все в разный p или span, разницы особо нет.

Вот к примеру у меня есть календарь, в нем 5 блоков, с числами от 10 до 14. я в input укажу "13, 15.00, пойти на улицу", нужно чтобы код как-то отследил из всех 5 блоков, блок с нужным числом - это 13, и вставил туда всю информацию

Answer (score 0):

Здесь почему то не работает но проверить можно здесь: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/WBeyOV

```js
var data = document.querySelector('.data');
var button = document.querySelector('#btn');
button.onclick = function () {

var name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
var surname = document.querySelector('#surname').value;
var age = document.querySelector('#age').value;
var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
 data.innerHTML = 'Имя ' + name + '<br>Фамилия '+ surname + '<br> Возраст ' +age + '<br> email ' + email+'<br><br>' ;
};
```

```html
<div class="data"></div>


Имя <input type="text" id='name'><br>
Фамилия <input type="text" id='surname'><br>
Возраст <input type="text" id="age"><br>
email <input type="text" id="email"><br>
<button id="btn">Clickme!</button>
```

Comment: Вот к примеру у меня есть календарь, в нем 5 блоков, с числами от 10 до 14. я в input укажу "13, 15.00, пойти на улицу", нужно чтобы код как-то отследил из всех 5 блоков, блок с нужным числом - это 13, и вставил туда всю информацию.

Comment: вы же видите там + name + ? и ещё там есть data.innerHTML а вот data это блок куда выводить , можно к примеру назначить кучу всяких блоков через querySelector("имя блок/тега");  и в него уже делать innerHTML тоже таким же способом + row + где row это переменная в которой лежим имя input

Comment: это вот про это у тебя были вопросы?

Comment: ну да ... но только единственно что я хотел узнать как вывести каждое слово из массива в отдельный параграф ...к примеру имеем ["str1", "str2", "str3"] и каждое сделать в цикле в `<p>str1</p>` и т д  понимаешь ? я могу вывести весь массив в один блок или параграф а вот в отдельные параграфы нет